# How to print an html file as a report after a successful build, in Jenkins?

Tags: html, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

My current Jenkins Version: **Jenkins 2.204.4**

I have a python program generating an HTML Report(only contains a table).
I need to print this as the build report after a successful Jenkins pipeline build.
I tried using the dashboard plugin(iframe portlet) and htmlpublisher plugin but cannot get them to print it as a build report. 
Also, I want to keep only one file and not have multiple files doing multiple things. Is it possible?

*This is the last stage from the pipeline*

```
stage("publish HTML Table") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def outputhtml = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'ls -atrl ./output |tail -1|cut -d" " -f11'
                    println outputhtml
                    def htmlfolder = "output/".concat(outputhtml)


                    publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true, escapeUnderscores: false, keepAll: false, reportDir: htmlfolder, reportFiles: 'final_result.html', reportName: 'Vulnerability Test Report', reportTitles:''])
                    createSummary(icon:"star-gold.png",text: "${outputhtml}")

                }
            }
        }
```

edit:

```
createSummary(icon: "notepad.png", text: readFile('./'.concat(html_folder.trim().concat("/${final_html}".trim()))))
```

This works. There was a dependency issue. https://plugins.jenkins.io/badge/ is the plugin that we need.